# Where to hook a coding convention script?

Tags: c++, git, mercurial, coding-style

When working in large teams code styling tools are often used to enforce coding convention compliance. The problem is not to find such a tool. It is more the question of, when you execute this tool? When do you execute this tool (e.g. astyle)? I worked in projects, that are using the first two approaches.

**In a separate script**

- Cannot interfere with other tools.
- User has control about executing the script.
- User is not enforced to use the tool.

**When building**

- Before building will ensure, that only compliant code will be built.
- May slow down build time.
- Enforces the user to use this tool.

**As a pre-commit hook**

- Will ensure, that only compliant code will be committed and pushed.
- Bugs in the tool get untested into the repository.

**In another way I don't know...**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set up controls in a `pre-commit` hook (in git) but:

- you have to distribute that hook
- one can bypass it (`git commit --no-verify`)

So in a DVCS, the best place is in a [`pre-receive` hook on the server side](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks), that is on the server considered hosting the "blessed" repos (the ones being used by everyone)

You can use it to enforce all kind of policies:

- versioning policies (see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/caniszczyk/1327469) which disallows deleting branches without a `/`, disallows non fast-forward on branches without a `/`, disallows deleting tags without a `/`, disallows unannotated tags to be pushed)
- launching external processes (like [unit tests](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2011/06/30/how-to-automatically-run-unit-tests-from-a-git-push/))

Comment: So, you think that's the best practice?

Comment: @StefanWeiser yes, enforcing policies in a central place is easier to maintain and evolve.